# Passing a DatePicker value to an Intent

Tags: android, android-intent, datepicker

I have a simple form with a DatePicker component on it. The user can enter their date of birth and then submit the form. Once submitted they are shown a review of what they entered into the form. I have every other component on the form working apart from the DatePicker. I am successfully passing a value from the DatePicker into my Intent but for some reason I am getting a very strange, undesired date...

Does anyone know how I can retrieve the actual values the user put in? Below is a screen of what I am getting in the emulator.

[image: Screenshot of Emulator]

This is the part of my code in my onCreate method where I put the date info into the intent

```
Date myDate = new Date(date.getDayOfMonth(), date.getMonth(), date.getYear());
            i.putExtra("dob", myDate.toString());
```

And then in the activity to show the results this is the code where I display the information pulled from the intent.

```
dob.setText("Their date of birth is: " + extras.get("dob"));
```

As you can see I do successfully get output, it's just not the date that I select on the DatePicker itself. I get no runtime errors at all. It's a formatting thing I think. Not sure though so any feedback is appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I corrected the issue. Rather then creating a Date object and passing it into my intent I decided to retrieve the values from the DatePicker and storing them in integer variables.

```
            int day = date.getDayOfMonth();
            int month = date.getMonth();
            int year = date.getYear();

            i.putExtra("day", day);
            i.putExtra("month", month);
            i.putExtra("year", year);
```

Following this I then retrieved the values from the Intent in the new Activity, formatted them and displayed them in a TextView.

```
    int day = extras.getInt("day");
    int month =extras.getInt("month");
    int year = extras.getInt("year");
    dob.setText("Their date of birth is: " + String.valueOf(day) + "/" + String.valueOf(month + 1) + "/" + String.valueOf(year));
```

I had to add 1 to the month as for some reason If I chose January it would output 0.